# A question on the Isbell-Mrowka $\Phi$-space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to learn the  Isbell-Mrowka $\Phi$-space. Which paper or book is helpful for a beginner to learn Isbell-Mrowka $\Phi$-space. It is better that the literature  includes not only conclusitions but also detailed proofs.

Any links is also welcome. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/ has a nice introduction. What about the original paper?

Comment: Looking at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.5716v1.pdf, are you?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for the links. It is helpful for me.

Comment: I also wrote http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461585/mrówka-spaces-are-first-countable as an intro