# What are some topologies without a countable basis?

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking for some topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ that do not have a countable basis. Specifically, I want something where some of the open sets can not be written as a countable union of basis elements. I'm trying to figure out why the definition of a topology states that the union of arbitrarily many open sets is open and I haven't found any examples that require more than a countable union.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about the discrete topology?

Comment: Give an uncountable space the particular point topology.  (This example is also connected.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fairly familiar topologies on $\Bbb R$ that do not have countable bases are the discrete topology, the cofinite topology, the co-countable topology, and the [Sorgenfrey topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) (also called the lower limit topology). One that has some importance as a counterexample is the [Michael line](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/michael-line-basics/), and another is the [rational sequence topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265236/compactness-properties-of-rational-sequence-topology).

Answer (score 0):

Take the discrete topology on $\Bbb R$ as a very easy example.

The Sorgenfrey line is another classic: this has as basic open sets all sets of the form $[x,y)$ where $x < y$. This is separable ($\Bbb Q$ is dense) but does not have a countable base.

The Michael line topology on $\Bbb R$ is the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ where we add all irrational points as isolated points (so it has subbase $\mathcal{T}_e \cup \mathscr{P}(\Bbb P)$ e.g.)